# Atomic Operation Vs STM

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, multicore, atomic

I was trying some benchmark over these two ( Software transactional memory & Atomic Operation , i guess both are not same ), though i have not done much using STM ( it seems hard to use ) ,but i successfully tried counting benchmark i.e. all the threads are incrementing a shared counter 50mn times, and noticed that atomic operation works better than STM.

So i want to know since STM are not fully developed , do they perform well in realistic situation than Atomic operation?
Has some one switched to other because of performance ? please share the information..

 related journal i found on the web is  [Concurrent programming without locks](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1233307.1233309)

P.S. I am using JAVA as programming language. STM :- multi-verse. AtomicOperatinn: AtomicInteger.

Comment: They have different purpose - I wouldn't choose one of the other based on performance.

Comment: If you only incremented a counter 50 million times this won't be very long. I would run the test for at least 2-5 seconds.

Comment: If you count to 250 million, this can take 5 seconds. Note: the optimal number of threads to use for counting is 1 which can give you some odd results. I suggest you try a test which is faster when you use more threads.

Comment: @peter okay:) but test like-what operation over link-list/hashmap ?    @johan thanks :-)

Comment: create a test which based on how you intend to use it.  You may find that STM is slower, but the difference is so marginal it doesn't matter. Or you might find it makes a big difference for a realistic example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Atomic operations and STMs are **very different** beasts. In particular, atomic operations are much "lower level" constructs - in fact, atomic operations of various kinds are generally used to *implement* STM. Basically:

- An atomic operation allows you to do a concurrency-safe update of a **single object**. This is easy and fast, typically just a single instruction on modern hardware.
- STM allows you do to a concurrency-safe update of **multiple objects**. This is complex.

STM systems therefore need to add additional book-keeping overhead to manage the complexity of a transactional update - so if you only need to update a single object an atomic operation will nearly always be faster.

Also, you should be aware that there is no consensus on the best way to design STM systems - it's an active research topic and there are many tradeoffs involved. So what performs well on one STM system might not perform well on another STM system etc.

For example: my [favourite STM system at the moment is Clojure's](http://clojure.org/refs) - it's particularly appealing because it supports multi-version concurrency control and never impedes readers - which gives a significant performance advantage in many common scenarios.

Comment: @mikrea great.. made my day... thanks.. :) ... Do you have any blog / sharable-content over the work done by you ? ..

Comment: Don't have anything public at the moment (stealth mode startup!) but if you are interested in this topic I highly recommend the following video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey or any of the great online articles about Clojure's STM. You can also browse my StackOverflow answers for various examples....